# System.ArgumentException: ORA-22062: invalid input string [161.252.2.150]

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql

Hi i want sent my ip adress to oracle db but i get this error " System.ArgumentException: ORA-22062: invalid input string [161.252.2.150] " How can i solve that problem.

```
 string ipCheck = "";
 ipCheck = host.AddressList[3].ToString();
 response.MSG_STR = db.UserIpCheck(ipCheck.ToString());
```

Comment: I can say with absolute certainty that that is _not_ your IP address. My suggestion is passing a valid IP address instead (i.e. one whose octet values are between 0 and 255 inclusive).

Comment: We would need to see the PL/SQL code. And also the code which actually calls the PL/SQL